# ListView Button does not update background properly

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, imagebutton

I have ListView and it the has a layout that utilizes an ImageButton (btnAdd).

The problem I am having is when I press the ImageButton within the layout that is populated in the ListView the ImageButton is supposed to change its background from grey to green.

This operation works properly, but when there are mulitple items in the ListView the ImageButton background changes on the bottom ListView item and not necessarily the ListView's ImageButton clicked.

**What am I missing? Should I be referencing the item's position within the ListView?**

```
@Override
    public View getItemView(final ParseUser pUser, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.search_detail, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(pUser, v, parent);

        ParseImageView todoImage = (ParseImageView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.imageViewSearch);
        ParseFile imageFile = pUser.getParseFile("photo");
        if (imageFile != null) {
            todoImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
            todoImage.loadInBackground();
        }

        // Add the title view
        final TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewSearch);
        titleTextView.setText(pUser.getUsername());

        btnAdd = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonAdd);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                Drawable background = v.getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.ui_border_green);
                Drawable img = v.getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.ico_friend_add_green);

                btnAdd.setBackground(background);
                btnAdd.setImageDrawable(img);
```

Comment: you need save background change in one place like one property of your class then set right value in `getView` instead of changing background in `onClick`, then in `onClick` change value of that and call `notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: Any chance of explaining this more clearly?